# How can I move the Gimp Text Tool (not the text layer)

Tags: text, gimp

when editing text in gimp the text tool is displayed on the screen.
Sometimes the text tool is blocking my view when adjusting or if I zoom in a lot, is not displayed in the visible portion of the screen.

How can I move the text tool itself, so that it is in a place where it does not obstruct any important part of the image.

Btw: This is the text tool: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't (this is a rather common complaint).